# Write a method cut(LinkList x) that divides the list x into two (roughly) equal halves and puts the second half at the front of the first half

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list, singly-linked-list

Example: The cut method invoked on the linked list:

```
f{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}
```

will return the linked list:

```
f{5,6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4}
```

LinkList Cut() Method

```
public static LinkList Cut(LinkList x) {
        LinkList front = new LinkList();
        LinkList back = new LinkList();
        while(!x.isEmpty){
            front.insertLast(x.removeFirst().data);
            if(!x.isEmpty){
                back.insertFirst(x.removeLast().data);
            }
        }
        while(!back.isEmpty){
            front.insertFirst(back.removeLast().data);

        }
        return front;

       }
```

First and Last, remove and insert methods.

```
public void insertFirst(int data){
        start = new Node(0);
        if(start == null){
            System.out.println("list is empty if");
        }else{
            start.link = head.link;
            start.data = 20;
            head.link = start;
        }
    }

    public void insertLast(int data) {

        start = new Node(0);
        if(start == null){
            System.out.println("List is empty il");
        }else{
            ptr = head;
            while(ptr.link != null){
                ptr = ptr.link;
            }
            ptr.link = start;
            start.data = 20;
        }
    }

    public Node removeFirst(){
        ptr = head.link;
        if(ptr == null){
            System.out.println("The list is empty");
        }else{
            ptr1 = ptr.link;
            head.link = ptr1;
        }
        return ptr;
    }

    public Node removeLast() {
        ptr = head;
        if(ptr.link == null)
        {
            System.out.println("List is Empty rl");
        }else{
            while(ptr.link != null){
                ptr1 = ptr;
                ptr = ptr.link;
            }
            ptr1.link = null;
        }
        return ptr;
    }
```

main();

```
LinkList list = new LinkList();
LinkList.head = new Node(1);
LinkList.head.link = new Node(2);
LinkList.head.link.link = new Node(3);
LinkList.head.link.link.link = new Node(4);
LinkList.head.link.link.link.link = new Node(5);
LinkList.head.link.link.link.link.link = new Node(6);
LinkList.head.link.link.link.link.link.link = new Node(7);
System.out.println("Link List Element: ");
list.printList(head);
list.Cut(list);
System.out.println("");
System.out.println("Cut Half Link List Element: ");
list.printList(head);
```

Output.

```
Link List Element: 
1 
2 
3 
4 
5 
6 
7 
The list is empty
```

what's wrong in my code, why it's show the list is empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved by simple and straight forward method of Linking the "head" of the list to its "tail" and updating the head.

The below function returns the updated head of the List.(C++).

```
Node *CutTheList(Node *head)
{
  int sizeList=0;  // Contains the size of the List
  Node *tracker=head; // temporary tracker

  while(tracker!=NULL){ sizeList++; tracker=tracker->next;} // Counts the Size of the List
  tracker=head;

  while(tracker->next!=NULL){tracker=tracker->next;} // Assigns the head to tail.
  tracker->next=head;

  int sizehalf=sizeList/2; //Size of the halved List.
  tracker=head;

  while(--sizehalf){ tracker=tracker->next; } //Update the head
  head=tracker->next; 
  tracker->next=NULL;

  return head;
 }
```